# cell animation, uitableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation

I was downloading an Pizza pizza application for IPhone. There is very cool animation for a cell.

If you click on particular cell, it will expand down and show you more controllers.

Please look at [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h97ox.png) (first state ) and at [link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBky7.png) (second state when you are clicking on the cell)

**Question** : what is the right way to achieve this animation.

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing new about this animation. Its pretty straight forward, and it will just depend on how you want to effect this change.

For example, start off with the `cells` as shown in your first image. Touching a cell will call the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and you will need to increase the size of the cell, and provide the new cell (which is the image of the second link). Call `tableView reloadData` to effect this change.  Use`UIAnimation` that will animate the cell from your first state to second state for a period of 0.5 seconds (how fast you want it to be)

Make sure that during the animation period, your cell is NOT selectable. 
`cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO`

You can do this with other animation frameworks, but `UIAnimation` should do the trick. (Refer to examples of `UIAnimation` if you need help with it)

Answer (score 1):

Every cell you see is a section Header View with button.When you touch the button,the table reload data in this section,then you can see the real cell view in this section. The cell view is a custom view with a lot of controllers.